# What is this hierarchy of an empty and a collection, and how do I get to the mesh inside?

Tags: groups, collections, outliner

I got some plants from [here](https://3dzip.org/free-model-darstellungsart-freebie-9-jungle-plants/free-model-from-darstellungsart-freebie-9-jungle-plants/) and they are gorgeous. However, I ended up moving some files and the textures broke, so I diligently went back and fixed them one by one. The last bit was doing the stems and leaves of this plant here:

[image]

Now, the screenshot is what I see when I click-select the leaves. An empty at the bottom (see the stems, I think that's an empty, at least…) and a dark-orange selection border around the leaves. I figured the empty and the leaves mesh were parented so I looked into the side-thingy and this is what it looks like:

[image]

Now, that orange icon is one I'm not familiar with, and I can't find anything in [the docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/outliner.html). I can't go into edit mode: no matter I many times I press <kbd>TAB</kbd>, the mode never changes, and in fact nothing other than Object mode is available in the top-left drop-down control in the viewport.

Suffice to say, this isn't giving me access to the material, so I can't fix the texture. I'm genuinely stumped. Any pointers?

Comment: Hello :). The orange box icon is a *Collection Instance*. It cannot be edited, it's just a link to some other collection - named *Planta*. Find the original *Planta* collection (it can be in different file/scene) and repair the texture there.

Comment: Aha! Thanks Jachym, I could swear I imported the mesh outright instead of linking it and never looked back. That makes sense! So I either go back to the original mesh or simply reimport it avoiding linking, right? I only applied affine transforms so it should be easy to replace the thing if I go for the latter.

Comment: That's right. You can use *File > Append* to fully copy things from other files. The *Colection Instance* is just a link, you can delete it without losing any original data :).

Comment: @JachymMichal Do you want to add this as an answer so I can mark it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The orange box icon is a [*Collection Instance*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/properties/instancing/collection.html#collections-and-dynamic-linking).

- It can't be edited, it's just a link to some other collection, that needs to be edited.
- To import assets from other files, make sure to use  *File > Append* the collection.
- Then it's imported with all objects as separate items.

*Importing all objects as separate items using File > Append*
[image]